# R coxph on indicator categorical variables

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to compute hazard ratios with a categorical variable, but it doesn't make sense to define any of them of a reference factor. The comparisons I would like to are each group individually compared to every other sample (i.e. samples labeled A vs. all samples not labeled A; samples labeled B vs. all samples not labeled B). By default, coxph would compare each group to the reference group (i.e. samples labeled B vs. samples labeled A; samples labeled C vs. samples labeled A). However, if I try to encode them as dummy variables to force it this way, the last one always gives NA results. Is there a way to do what I'm trying, or is there a way to fix my current approach?

Example:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(Time, Status) ~ class_A + class_B + 
    class_C + class_D, data = data)
                    coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z        p
class_A         -2.1185    0.1202   0.4093 -5.175 2.27e-07
class_B        -1.9059    0.1487   0.6825 -2.792  0.00523
class_C       -1.1212    0.3259   0.4179 -2.683  0.00729
class_D             NA        NA   0.0000     NA       NA
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of your data so we can see how you got to your results? You can use `dput(data)` and post it here, so we have the data too

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, your variable only has four categories. Then you should pass only three of the dummy variables because the four of them sum to one and create a collinearity with the constant (baseline) term (hence you get NAs in the output). The resulting coefficients are additive effects to the model with the omitted class.

Using three dummies is what R does by default when passing a factor as single variable. If you want to change this behaviour you need to change "constrast" type in the R options (e.g. https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-set-the-contrasts-for-your-data-with-r/) or transform the coefficients obtained.